# Don't know why XML Schema isn't well-formed?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I got a very simple problem, which is related to a given XML Schema file you can see below my post. It's from an exam I have to write in a week and its a question about the schema being well-formed.

The error is already marked yellow and I got the hint that it's about namespaces, but in the end I have no idea how to resolve the problem. My first thought was that the type-definition `Type="Book"` needs a prefix like `Type="urn:Book"`, but I'm not sure at all.

I thank you for any advice that may help me to fix my lack of knowledge in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are specifying that `Book` is in the `urn:schemaS` namespace using `targetNamespace` attribute. For this to work, you need to define a namespeace prefix for `urn:schemaS` and the qualify it in `type="nsPrefix:Book"`.

[Read this tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer, it helped me a lot and I guess I got an idea about the function of namespaces, especially in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a named `complexType` its name is a qualified one, associated with the target namespace - so what you are declaring is a type `Book` in the `urn:schema5` namespace.

When you reference the type you have to specify its qualified name, and the schema does NOT default to the target namespace, it uses the normal XML namespace declarations. Because you have none, you are trying to use a type `Book` in the default namespace (''), that does not exist.

You have to either add a namespace declaration:

```
<xs:schema  
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:schema5="urn:schema5"
  targetNamespace="urn:schema5"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

and then use it

```
    <xs:element name="book" type="schema5:Book" maxOccurs="3"/>
```

or (my preferred choice) declare you target namespace as the default one:

```
<xs:schema  
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="urn:schema5"
  targetNamespace="urn:schema5"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

and then you don't have to do anything else.